# Android SeekBar - How to make smaller at right and bigger at left

Tags: android, slider, seekbar

I want SeekBar as follow: 
- Slide to the right: value is decreased: exp, from 255 down to 0
- Slide to the left: value is increased: exp, from 0 up to 255


Or, if SeekBar cannt do something like that, what component should I use?
Please give me advice!

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

It's simply. Take a SeekBar, set it from 0 to 255, and on change calculate the output value based on SeekBar's progress the way you like.

Comment: Actually, I do in each OnSeekBarChangeListener: 
value_to_display = 255 - progress;
Not only set it from 0 to 255 ^^
Simply :)